# Modify json structure scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a json like this:

```
 [
  {
    "ser": 345,
    "City": "New York",
    "Gen": 1
  },
  {
    "ser": 55,
    "City": "New York",
    "Gen": 2
  },
  {
    "ser": 19,
    "City": "New York",
    "Gen": 3
  }
 ]
```

I want to make some query to this json ( example: SELECT SUM(ser) AS Serlab, City, Gen FROM libri GROUP BY City, Gen ORDER BY City)...i need spark rdd to make this.

After this query i should modify the structure of my input json in this new:

```
[ { "label": [1,2,3] //that is the Gen value, 
     "values": [ 
                 { "label":"New York" 
                   "values":["200","10","66"]  //is the ser about all Gen (for eexample 200 is ser is for label/gen 1 .. 10 is for label/gen 2 etc.
                 },
                { "label":"London" 
                  "values":["500","150","46"] 
                }, 
                { "label":"London" 
                  "values":["500","150","46"] 
                }, 
                .
                . 
                . 
                . 
                . 
               ] 
  } 
]
```

And then i send this new JSON to a Http request
How can i make this in scala,play,spark? Please help me :)

Comment: You should look at Spark dataframe. Also read about the documentation in the official website, transforming an RDD to another is quite easy and is similar to how collections API works in scala

Comment: 1) i use spark and rdd for take the json from hadoop and then make some query.

2) Then i have a class that take the json's value like this: 
`case class Book(ser: Int, city: String, gen: Int)`

3) I create a seq of book. 

4) So now i want to modify this seq in a list that looks like the json output.
At the end i will convert this list in a json.
How can i make this last step

Comment: @RamkumarVenkataraman have you got any solution?

Comment: please help me :)